# Subscribe/Unsubscribe link to a group's content type using Notifications & OG

Tags: 6, organic-groups, notifications

We're using the Notifications module with Organic Groups (in Drupal 6). We have been writing our own UI module for Notifications so that it is simpler to use and more tailored for our client's needs. One of the remaining tasks is to include a link in the groups that a user can click on to subscribe/unsubscribe to a group's content type.

Does anyone know what structure the subscribe URL needs to be to allow this?

I know for a normal thread it is: `notifications/subscribe/[uid]/thread/nid/[nid]` and `notifications/unsubscribe/[sid]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I eventually figured it out:-

```
notifications/subscribe/[uid]/grouptype/group,type/[gid],[type]
```